# How can I quickly close multiple VI instances in different GNU-Screen tabs?

Tags: unix, vim, gnu-screen

I often have around 10 tabs in GNU-Screen open with all of them having vim open to a different file. If I just kill the Screen session, then VIM doesn't cleanup (.swp files are still there), so I usually have to go to each tab individually and type ":wq" and the "exit" to kill the screen tab. Any faster ways to do this?

Comment: How are you killing screen?  If I send a TERM to screen, all the swap files are cleaned up.  Do you mean "detach"? Or do you mean 'send SIGKILL'?  If the latter...don't do that.

Comment: I think "killall vim" is what I was looking for.

What usually happens is that I will detach the screen and then at some point later, shut down the computer. So screen just closes in the restart.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
killall vim
```

;-)

Comment: Won't this also leave the swap files on the filesystem?

Answer (score 0):

I do something similar and ran into the same problem. What worked for me was to just turn off the creation of .swp files so vim doesn't care if I close the whole session at once. In my .vimrc:

```
set noswapfile
```

Of course this only works because I'm in the habit of saving often and almost everything is in version control so I could get it back if some catastrophe happened. Your mileage may vary if you have a different use case or work flow.